# app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease' while generating release apk

Tags: android

Hello I have developed one app and its completed.Now i am tryting to create release apk but i am getting following exception

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/HttpMessage.class
```

My app build.gradle is as follows
I am not getting why the error is occured in my app.debug app is running perfectely.I am getting error while creating release apk

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories { flatDir {
dirs 'libs' }
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'org/apache/http/entity/mime/version.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/pom.xml'
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.XXXX.XXXX"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
 }


dependencies {
compile(name: 'peb-lib', ext: 'aar')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.0.3@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
compile 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
compile 'com.vlonjatg.android:app-tour:1.0'
compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:1.0.3'
compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.1@aar'
compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:+'
```

}

Please give solution because i want to publish app on playstore.Thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated (for now), but you should remove `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` and update `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'` to use `8.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

You are using two distinct `aar` or `jar` dependencies which includes the apache http client. That is your problem. There are some ways to inspect the content of the `jar` or `aar` file like [jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx/releases), but since you are a beginner a trail and error way should be fine too.

So first if you don't have `jar` dependencies please remove this line:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Now exclude the apache classes from your dependencies for example:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
```

needs to be converted to:

```
compile('com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
```

If it still not compile try the next dependency and so on. That should remove the duplicate classes.

Good luck!